# Accidentally executed luksFormat instead of luksOpen

Tags: raid, luks, mdadm, restore

I have two disks as RAID-1 encrypted via LUKS:

```
# blkid
...
/dev/md0: UUID="x-x-x-x-x" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
```

Accidently I executed `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/md0` instead of `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md0 secure`. luksFormat returned `WARNING: Device /dev/md0 already contains a 'crypto_LUKS' superblock signature.`

Now I cant use open anymore, the following lines provide more information:

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md0 secure
Device /dev/md0 is not a valid LUKS device.
# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/md0
Device /dev/md0 is not a valid LUKS device.
# hexdump -C /dev/md0 | grep LUKS
00000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00  |LUKS..........@.|
hexdump: /dev/md0: Input/output error
```

Is there anything I can do, to get my data?

Comment: What happened after the "WARNING: Device /dev/md0 already contains a 'crypto_LUKS' superblock signature."? Did you go on with the format or did you abandon it?   Also, the "Input/output error" lets me believe you have a drive with a problem.

Comment: There wasn't any additional output. I interpreted it as "found data but will format it anyway".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man cryptsetup` (section luksFormat):
WARNING:  Doing  a luksFormat on an existing LUKS container will make all data of the old container permanently irretrievable, unless you have a header backup.

I guess you don't have a header backup and therefore your data will be history.
Sorry for the bad news.

Nevertheless, the `hexdump: /dev/md0: Input/output error` indicates a problem with one of your drives!!

Comment: You are correct regarding the man-pages and also regarding the drives: `dmesg` shows many messages like `Buffer I/O error on dev md0, logical block 64, async page read`.